# Good data access methodology(ies) for planning tool?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, data-access-layer

I'm building/maintaining some planning tools, with the following characteristics:

-data is loaded (read-only) from MsAccess/SQLServer into C# framework 3.5. Data is loaded into SQLServer/MsAccess from the ERP system.

-Significant amounts of maintenance data are loaded (say in total 2000.000 records from various tables), all this data is needed simultaneously to do the planning.

Currently, I am using typed datatables that I fill using tableadapter. I then iterate over the rows in each table, creating custom objects that hold the same data. The rest of my code only works with those custom objects.

What are alternatives to this approach, and what are the pros/cons of the alternatives over this approach in terms of maintainability and loading speed (from SQL Server/MSAccess into memory)?

Main disadvantage of current approach is that I need to load entire tables, while in some cases I would be able to dynamically determine which records I would need to retrieve. But the current framework does not appear to give easy support for this.

Comment: Your usage of SQLServer/MsAccess is curious. Is your tool designed to be semi-database agnostic?

Comment: The tool does not need to work with live data, SQLServer data can be filled overnight to reduce demand on server.

Comment: What are the problems that you are experiencing at the moment with your approach?

Comment: I added a comment on problems that I experience. Furthermore, I am not sure about maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

your approach sounds very reasonable to me.
it's main advantage is that it's [very simple](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/kiss.html).
The only reason I see to change it is if you indeed have performance problems.
In that case, I would suggest loading your data in chunks (say, 5000 rows at a time, something like that).
If you're using different servers for your app and for the database engine, you might benefit from loading the next batch in a separate thread while processing the current batch.

But, again- if it's working fine the way it is- than it's fine.

p.s. Like billinkc, I'm curious about msAccess- can it really perform well with those volumes of data?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of performance and to avoid reinventing the wheel, I would strongly consider using an ETL library - for instance RhinoETL